# Can SSIS import TXT records in exact same order as they are in TXT file? If not (by default), then how?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, data-warehouse

I have records in a flat file that have what you might consider to be master records with detail records following the master they relate to, until the master record.

Here is an example:

```
Order123, Customer1, 1/1/2018
Item1, $1
Item2, $1
Order124, Customer2, 1/1/2018
Item1, $1
Item4, $2
```

The file has no line numbers or any kind of sequencing built in, nor does it use foreign keys to relate master to detail.

If I were to use SSIS to import the raw TXT data into a flexible table with columns designed to take various datatypes (i.e. nvarchar(255), or similar), I could iterate over the values after the import, and relate the values in Line #2 and Line #3 with Order123; and consequently, Lines #5 and #6 with Order124.

The table holding the raw data will use a simple RecordID identity column with an integer incrementing by one.

*It doesn't really matter, but if you're curious, the actual data I'm referring to is the Retrosheet data event files. It's a collection of all Major League Baseball data. A real file could be downloaded from a link on this page:
https://www.retrosheet.org/game.htm*

I seem to recall that you could not import TXT data into a table and expect that the order of the rows would match the order of the TXT lines. When I do small tests of this, however, the records do appear in the same order as the source file. I suspect that my small test results were too good to be true and not a fail safe prediction on how it will turn out.

**In summary:**

How do I use SSIS to import data, inserting SQL records in the same order as the original flat file?

Comment: Thinking back, was it the "multi phase data pump" in the DTS (Data Transformation Services, prior to SSIS) that dis-ordered raw data? Maybe that is why I question this?

Comment: I'm trying to confirm this, but I think that they do come in sequentially.  Even still, you wouldn't be able to query / process them sequentially without a way to order the data.  You would need to have something like an IDENTITY column on the table.

Comment: The source will be consumed in its natural order. After that though, there's no guarantee it will stay that way. You may need to assign a row number as the data comes in and use that subsequently if you have to Sort it again. You could feed the source directly through a Script Component (Transformation) task that counts up each time it processes a row, and assigns that counter to a new Output column.

Comment: I also wonder if you need to set an attribute on the component to ensure the order is kept. Yes, true about needing the identity, such as RecordID INT Identity (1,1).

Comment: Actually there is no GTD... learned this the hard way.  I ended up loading as a single_blob and then parsed with a sequence number

Comment: Digging around, with credit to Squill, Cory, and John for influencing my searches, it seems the solution requires either a script component (Cory) to add line numbers to the flat file before importing, or setting the commit size to a single row (which will be slow).

Comment: script component to add row numbers is the way to go.   It's only few lines of C# or vb

Comment: I'd use a script task and use a split function. if the result is length 3 then it is a header and if not then it is a detail row. instatiate a string orderNo outside of the current row processing to save the current key so you can write to details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just typed this out so there might be a few errors in syntax but it should get you close.

You will need to set up 2 different outputs.

Order of load will not matter as you are adding a foreign key to the detail table.

```
public string orderNo; /// on the OUTSIDE

public main()



string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines([filename]);

foreach(var line in lines)
{
   string[] cols = line.Split(',');
   if(cols.Length == 3)
   {
      orderNo = cols[0];
      Output0Buffer.AddRow();
      Output0Buffer.OrderNo = cols[0].ToString();
      Output0Buffer.Customer = cols[1].ToString();
      Output0Buffer.OrderDate = DateTime.Parse(cols[2].ToString().Trim());
   }
   else
   {
      Output1Buffer.AddRow();
      Output1Buffer.OrderNo = orderNo;
      Output1Buffer.Item = cols[0].ToString();
      Output1Buffer.Amt = cols[1].ToString(); //This needs to be parsed later.
   }
}
```

FOLLOW UP:

I just reviewed the site you are trying to download from. And the file is more complicated than you led on by your question.

Split still seems safe to use but you will have to trim some quotewrapped strings (names) but it looks like there are no quote wrapped commas (at least in the examples). If that is the case you need to use REGEX to split.

I would change the logic to use switch and case and base it on cols[0] being one of the 8 types.

Save ID on the outside and write to each of the 7 other possible datasets this creates for linkage to parent. You will have to use the same strategy for other records that need to be tied to a different parent (I think comment is an example).

GOOD LUCK with all this. Plays do not look easy to interpret!

Comment: I forgot a major thing. I forgot Split! I fixed the code and it should work now.

Comment: This looks like a fun project. What are you going to do with the data?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes, flat files are processed in order, as long as you aren't applying any kind of sorting.

I was able to process the Retrosheet files by creating a table in my DB that had an identity column, and a varchar column long enough to hold each line of the file (I chose 100). I then set up my flat file connection with `Ragged Right` formatting, defining the row delimiter as `{CR}{LF}`.

Comment: Would you be able to provide any reference that states that flat files are processed in order. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @digital-aaron - I currently have a ETL package that reads a CSV file and does specific tasks based on the first 2 rows. It has flat file source pushing to OLEDB destination DB table. Table has IDENTITY column. See this [link](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/import-large-text-file-keep-exact-row-order-ssis#post-3639737) about text file with 12 mil rows. Another [link](https://hansmichielscom.wordpress.com/2013/06/20/how-to-add-a-rownumber-to-a-data-flow-task-in-ssis-2012/) to add Row ID using script task.